# How to check if file exist in /data folder on android

Tags: android

I am trying to check if a file exist in /data or /recovery folder. I understand how to perform the check if its on external storage folder, but I want to make in the check on the /data.

Answer (score 1):

`/data` is protected by **ROOT** permissions. That means, your device must be rooted to perform such a check.

Comment: yes, I understand that, I have been able to do that without much troubles but at this moment, I want to delete a file from the /data. I also have my device rooted, thanks

Comment: @Ross any luck finding a solution?